# htaccess redirect for all categories converted to tags now showing 404

Tags: categories, redirect, tags, htaccess, 404-error

I have a WordPress site which syndicates content from a number of sources and auto creates categories and tags.

I have converted a large number of categories to tags which now leaves a ton of categories showing 404's. I started manually redirecting these but as expected this is a huge task.

I'm trying to find a way to use htaccess redirects, which can

1. detect all category 404s
2. redirect those to their /tag/tagterm/ equavalent

so all 404'ing /category/catterm to be redirected to /tag/tagterm equavalent

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Heree's a code solution, not htaccess. This first checks if current query is for a category page, then checks category existence, and if category not exists but a tag with the same name, it redirects to the tag page.

```
add_action('parse_request', 'wpse_parse_request');
function wpse_parse_request( $r ){
    if( isset($r->query_vars['category_name']) )
    {
        $cat = get_term_by('slug', $r->query_vars['category_name'], 'category');
        if( !isset($cat->term_id) )
        {
            $tag = get_term_by('slug', $r->query_vars['category_name'], 'post_tag');
            $link = get_term_link($tag);
            if( !is_wp_error($link) )
            {
                wp_redirect($link);
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this shazzad, does this go in my functions.php file? Will it remove the pages being flagged as 404 from the google bot's perspective?

Comment: Yes, these could go to `functions.php file`. And it should handle the googlebot's 404 for future crawl, as we are redirecting with `301` (wp_redirect function use 301 by default) status header, what means moved permanently.